# better understanding about @foreach on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i just want to ask how exactly @foreach in laravel works for examply code like this

```
@foreach ($users as $user)

@endforeach
```

i know $users value can be obtained from controller like this:

```
public function show()
{
    $users = users:find($id);

    return view('user_tab', compact('users'));
}
```

but i saw some tutorial on site that do @foreach like :

```
@foreach ($user->posts as $post)

@endforeach
```

what's posts without `$` stand for ??   i just dont know. i do already read laravel documentation about this on here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade but still cant understand it can someone explain it to me? thx for advance

Comment: `@foreach` these are helper in blade which compiles as internally `<?php foreach ?>` like this

Comment: its a parameter of an object

Comment: but what i dont understand if i do it poorly it always give some error like Property [artikels] does not exist on this collection instance. if i include @foreach ($user->posts as $post) like this so what i always do lopping it inside looping

Comment: It's all blade templating: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Answer (score 1):

> $user->posts

Here *'posts'* represents a model relationship. Go to your User model and you will find a function like this:

```
function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Posts::class);
}
```

This represents that a User can have multiple posts. You can directly get all the post of an user by calling this function once you get a user instance.

Hence in your code it is fetching all the posts of the specific user by `$user->posts` and then iterating over it in `@foreach` loop.

Answer (score -1):

if in your controller you call user with relation then you can access the related enter code here` like this

Comment: public function show()
{
    $users = users::with('Posts')
    ->find($id);

    return view('user_tab', compact('users'));
}

@foreach($user->Post as $post)
@endforeach